# Biopython, How do I print just the text of a sequence?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I want to put a list of sequences in an csv, however everything is returned as "seq('DNA sequence')". How do I print just the NT sequence.

```
primers = [Seq("CCGCGTTACATAGCATCGTACGCGTACG"),Seq("TGTTTGGTCCTGCCGGCCCTGCCTCAGCCGGATCCATGGTGAGCAAGGG")] # list is made in another function
print(primers)# Prints as "[Seq('CCGCGTTACATAGCATCGTACGCGTACG'), Seq('TGTTTGGTCCTGCCGGCCCTGCCTCAGCCGGATCCATGGTGAGCAAGGG')]"
```

Comment: Try cast each Seq to string before printing. i.e. str(Seq(...)).

Comment: Thanks, looping thorough it worked

Answer (score 4):

Printing a list of `Seq()` objects returns the `repr()` representation rather than the `str()` representation. The solution is to convert to `str()` or print each `Seq()` object individually:

```
>>> from Bio.Seq import Seq
>>> s = Seq("CCG")
>>> print(s)
CCG
>>> print([s])
[Seq('CCG')]
>>> print(repr(s))
Seq('CCG')
>>> print(repr(str(s)))
'CCG'
>>> print([str(s)])
['CCG']
>>> print(list(map(str,[s, s])))
['CCG', 'CCG']
```